# The verb かける in this sentence

Tags: translation, verbs

How should I translate the verb かける and the sentence as a whole?

> 階段に掃除機を**かけて**ください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

かける is simply the verb that is used with 掃除機.

> 掃除機をかける = "to vacuum-clean / to hoover"

In this case かける is usually written in *kana*, although the correct *kanji* would be 掛ける.

Similarly, one uses

> アイロンをかける = "to iron"
>   [雑巾]{ぞうきん}をかける・雑巾[掛]{が}け(を)する = "to wipe"